# Start and stop date fields vs. single date field for historical, hierarchical data

Tags: sql, hierarchy

In developing a historical and hierarchical SQL table, is it better to use start and stop date fields or a single date field for every date?  There are pros and cons for each, but I'm looking for evidence as to which is more optimized, elegant, and takes into account corner cases most effectively.

Example -

```
-- Start/Stop
create table roster (
    id bigint identity primary key,
    start_date date not null,
    stop_date date not null,
    employee_id int not null references employee (id),
    supervisor_id int not null references employee (id),
    unique(start_date, stop_date, employee_id)
)

-- Single Date
create table roster (
    id bigint identity primary key,
    row_date date not null,
    employee_id int not null references employee (id),
    supervisor_id int not null references employee (id),
    unique(row_date, employee_id)
)
```

Comment: I think it depends on what your business requirements are.

Comment: True, but given the schema examples above, which ones can be better optimized?  I'd lean towards the single date roster.  This means when you perform JOINs there is no need to use BETWEEN for "as of" dates, which is generally what historical hierarchies are used for.  However, you get a space savings with the date range version and possibly a simpler future hierarchy.  But I'm just looking for some evidence to support/discredit either side.